# Plot from external function to GUI axes in Matlab

Tags: matlab

I need to show the function I created "LinearOpticalElement.m" file into the GUI I created with axes in it. How should I go about it?

I have implemented cases just in case I need to add in more functions later on. How should I do it?

[image]
[image]

I have trouble with the GUI function calling another function which is LinearOpticalElementsGUI.m

```
function varargout = GUITest(varargin)
% GUITEST MATLAB code for GUITest.fig
%      GUITEST, by itself, creates a new GUITEST or raises the        existing
%      singleton*.
%
%      H = GUITEST returns the handle to a new GUITEST or the     handle to
%      the existing singleton*.
%
%      GUITEST('CALLBACK',hObject,eventData,handles,...) calls the    local
%      function named CALLBACK in GUITEST.M with the given input   arguments.
%
%      GUITEST('Property','Value',...) creates a new GUITEST or     raises the
%      existing singleton*.  Starting from the left, property value     pairs are
%      applied to the GUI before GUITest_OpeningFcn gets called.      An
%      unrecognized property name or invalid value makes property application
%      stop.  All inputs are passed to GUITest_OpeningFcn via varargin.
%
%      *See GUI Options on GUIDE's Tools menu.  Choose "GUI allows only one
%      instance to run (singleton)".
%
% See also: GUIDE, GUIDATA, GUIHANDLES

% Edit the above text to modify the response to help GUITest

% Last Modified by GUIDE v2.5 26-Oct-2018 18:51:49

% Begin initialization code - DO NOT EDIT
gui_Singleton = 1;
gui_State = struct('gui_Name',       mfilename, ...
                   'gui_Singleton',  gui_Singleton, ...
                   'gui_OpeningFcn', @GUITest_OpeningFcn, ...
                   'gui_OutputFcn',  @GUITest_OutputFcn, ...
                   'gui_LayoutFcn',  [] , ...
                   'gui_Callback',   []);
if nargin && ischar(varargin{1})
    gui_State.gui_Callback = str2func(varargin{1});
end

if nargout
    [varargout{1:nargout}] = gui_mainfcn(gui_State, varargin{:});
else
    gui_mainfcn(gui_State, varargin{:});
end
% End initialization code - DO NOT EDIT

% --- Executes just before GUITest is made visible.
function GUITest_OpeningFcn(hObject, eventdata, handles, varargin)
% This function has no output args, see OutputFcn.
% hObject    handle to figure
% eventdata  reserved - to be defined in a future version of MATLAB
% handles    structure with handles and user data (see GUIDATA)
% varargin   command line arguments to GUITest (see VARARGIN)

% Choose default command line output for GUITest
handles.output = hObject;

% Update handles structure
guidata(hObject, handles);

% This sets up the initial plot - only do when we are invisible
% so window can get raised using GUITest.
if strcmp(get(hObject,'Visible'),'off')
    %plot(rand(5));
end

% UIWAIT makes GUITest wait for user response (see UIRESUME)
% uiwait(handles.figure1);


% --- Outputs from this function are returned to the command line.
function varargout = GUITest_OutputFcn(hObject, eventdata, handles)
% varargout  cell array for returning output args (see VARARGOUT);
% hObject    handle to figure
% eventdata  reserved - to be defined in a future version of MATLAB
% handles    structure with handles and user data (see GUIDATA)

% Get default command line output from handles structure
varargout{1} = handles.output;

% --- Executes on button press in pushbutton1.
function pushbutton1_Callback(hObject, eventdata, handles)
% hObject    handle to pushbutton1 (see GCBO)
% eventdata  reserved - to be defined in a future version of MATLAB
% handles    structure with handles and user data (see GUIDATA)
axes(handles.axes1);
cla;

popup_sel_index = get(handles.popupmenu1, 'Value');
switch popup_sel_index
    case 1

        axes(LinearOpticalElementsGUI);


end


% -----------------------------------------------------------------    ---
function FileMenu_Callback(hObject, eventdata, handles)
% hObject    handle to FileMenu (see GCBO)
% eventdata  reserved - to be defined in a future version of MATLAB
% handles    structure with handles and user data (see GUIDATA)


% --------------------------------------------------------------------
function OpenMenuItem_Callback(hObject, eventdata, handles)
% hObject    handle to OpenMenuItem (see GCBO)
% eventdata  reserved - to be defined in a future version of MATLAB
% handles    structure with handles and user data (see GUIDATA)
file = uigetfile('*.fig');
if ~isequal(file, 0)
    open(file);
end

% --------------------------------------------------------------------
function PrintMenuItem_Callback(hObject, eventdata, handles)
% hObject    handle to PrintMenuItem (see GCBO)
% eventdata  reserved - to be defined in a future version of MATLAB
% handles    structure with handles and user data (see GUIDATA)
printdlg(handles.figure1)

% --------------------------------------------------------------------
function CloseMenuItem_Callback(hObject, eventdata, handles)
% hObject    handle to CloseMenuItem (see GCBO)
% eventdata  reserved - to be defined in a future version of MATLAB
% handles    structure with handles and user data (see GUIDATA)
selection = questdlg(['Close ' get(handles.figure1,'Name') '?'],...
                     ['Close ' get(handles.figure1,'Name') '...'],...
                     'Yes','No','Yes');
if strcmp(selection,'No')
    return;
end

delete(handles.figure1)


% --- Executes on selection change in popupmenu1.
function popupmenu1_Callback(hObject, eventdata, handles)
% hObject    handle to popupmenu1 (see GCBO)
% eventdata  reserved - to be defined in a future version of MATLAB
% handles    structure with handles and user data (see GUIDATA)

% Hints: contents = get(hObject,'String') returns popupmenu1     contents as cell array
%        contents{get(hObject,'Value')} returns selected item from popupmenu1


% --- Executes during object creation, after setting all properties.
function popupmenu1_CreateFcn(hObject, eventdata, handles)
% hObject    handle to popupmenu1 (see GCBO)
% eventdata  reserved - to be defined in a future version of MATLAB
% handles    empty - handles not created until after all CreateFcns     called

% Hint: popupmenu controls usually have a white background on     Windows.
%       See ISPC and COMPUTER.
if ispc && isequal(get(hObject,'BackgroundColor'),     get(0,'defaultUicontrolBackgroundColor'))
     set(hObject,'BackgroundColor','white');
end

set(hObject, 'String', {'RH Circular'});
```

And this is the LinearOpticalElementsGUI.m file

```
clear
clc
theta=0:2*pi/1000:2*pi;
x=cos(theta);
y=sin(theta);
x1(1)=0;
y1(1)=0;
xaxx=[-1;1];
xaxy=[0;0];
yaxx=[0;0];
yaxy=[-1;1];
figure('color','white');
for i=1:1:size(x')
    x1(2)=x(i);
    y1(2)=y(i);
    xcompx(1)=x(i);
    xcompy(1)=y(i);
    xcompy(2)=0;
    xcompx(2)=sqrt(x(i)^2+y(i)^2)*cos(theta(i));
    ycompx(1)=x(i);
    ycompy(1)=y(i);
    ycompx(2)=0;
    ycompy(2)=sqrt(x(i)^2+y(i)^2)*sin(theta(i));
    plot(xaxx,xaxy,'b',yaxx,yaxy,'g',x,y,'r',xcompx,xcompy,'-    b',ycompx,ycompy,'-g',x1,y1,'-ro')
    axis square;
    title('Right-Handed Circular polarization')
    getframe();
```

end

Comment: Please copy and paste the code rather than uploading images. It makes it easier for others to copy and paste *your* code.

Comment: You don't show the code for the optical element file so it is impossible to advise how to do this. Does it return any data?

Comment: Sorry my bad, I will upload the code up

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem seems  to be, that "LinearOpticalElementsGUI" is a *script* not a *function*. Scripts do not have a return value. So you could try to simply call the script instead of passing its non-existent return value to a function.

```
% --- Executes on button press in pushbutton1.
function pushbutton1_Callback(hObject, eventdata, handles)
% hObject    handle to pushbutton1 (see GCBO)
% eventdata  reserved - to be defined in a future version of MATLAB
% handles    structure with handles and user data (see GUIDATA)
axes(handles.axes1);
cla;

popup_sel_index = get(handles.popupmenu1, 'Value');
switch popup_sel_index
    case 1

        LinearOpticalElementsGUI;


end
```

This might show a new axes. So you could also try to call the plot function within your script like this: `plot(gca(), xaxx, ...)`

---

But it would actually be a better style to convert the script "LinearOpticalElementsGUI" to a function that has the axes handle as an argument.

```
function LinearOpticalElementsGUI(ax)

% "clc" and "clear" not useful
% ...
% "figure(...)" is not needed anymore
% ...

   plot(ax, xaxx, ...)

% ...
end
```

Comment: Hi, I'm not too sure what do you mean by that? "So you could also try to call the plot function within your script like this: plot(gca(), xaxx, ...)" 

Which means I need to write this code under the GUI file?

Comment: @AlvinLee ...In "LinearOpticalElementsGUI" add the first argument to the function call. Sorry  for being a little unclear.

Comment: Sorry for my little knowledge. Could you share on how or where should I place the code in?